# Why isn't this 3 line VBA application.importXML test app working?

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access

I am trying to understand Application.ImportXML to import an XML file into a MS Access table.

My understanding is if I specify an XML file, it will create a table, define the fields and import the data into those fields.

First question:  is that a correct understanding?

When I implement a simple test program, I get an error message I cannot resolve on my own.

Here is the XML file I'm using :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<EmpDetails>
<Employee>
<Name>ABC</Name>
<Dept>IT-Software</Dept>
<Location>New Delhi</Location>
</Employee>
<Employee>
<Name>XYZ</Name>
<Dept>IT-Software</Dept>
<Location>Chennai</Location>
</Employee>
<Employee>
<Name>IJK</Name>
<Dept>HR Operations</Dept>
<Location>Bangalore</Location>
</Employee>
</EmpDetails>
```

And this is the code I am using in Microsoft Access 2016 :

```
Function XMLtoTable()

    Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    x = objAccess.ImportXML("C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Projects\XML into ENEX\employee.xml", 1)

    MsgBox ("done")

End Function
```

And the error message I get :

[image]

When I press Debug, this line is highlighted :

```
x = objAccess.ImportXML("C:\Users\Mark\Documents\Projects\XML into ENEX\employee.xml", 1)
```

Since this is such basic program, I have no clue where to go from here?

I have the Reference Microsoft XML 3.0 turned on.

Thanks for any help,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `ImportXML` does not return anything so you should remove `x=` from the front of the line that calls the method. (And also remove the parentheses from around the file path.)

Then, since you appear to be calling this from another application, you need to *open the database* to which you want to append the XML. Currently, there's no database, so the XML can't be imported. Something like this:

```
Dim objAccess As Access.Application
Set objAccess = GetObject("C:\path\database name.mdb")    
'objAccess.Visible = True
objAccess.ImportXML "C:\Test\XML into ENEX\employee.xml", acAppendData
'objAccess.UserControl = True
```

When I do that Access imports the XML you show with no problem.